# Unable to load Ubuntu from Grub

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2

I installed Ubuntu on an HP laptop, which came with Windows 7. When I try to boot into Ubuntu, I only get a Grub screen. At the Grub screen, I tried to set the root drive by running the `ls` command but it just returns 'unknown filesystem' for all my partitions except one (which is FAT).

Interestingly enough, when I boot Ubuntu on a 'trial mode' through the bootable USB disk, I can see all the partitions including the one on which Ubuntu is installed. The file system is shown as ext3/ext4.

How do I solve this issue?

Comment: I removed the SD card on which I had installed Ubuntu. At the grub menu, the LS command still returned the same list of hd filesystems. So, I conclude that Ubuntu isn't able to recognize my SD card at the time of booting (but it recognizes  the card quite well when I boot using a bootable USB stick and launch Ubuntu in the 'trial' mode).

Has any one encountered a similar issue? How did you resolve it?

Answer (score 0):

Can confirm that I've encountered similar problem.
In the grub menu, select the advanced option (which is just below Ubuntu option in Grub menu) and press "Enter" and then run Ubuntu in recovery mode. Then there you will find a menu and select the update grub option. It will find and fix the problem. This worked for me.

Comment: Thanks. I don't get to a GUI menu. Just a grub command prompt. Not sure how to go to the recovery mode from there.